# Show custom automatic headers in excel for sql xml generated file

Tags: xml, excel, t-sql

I'm generating xml files from sql server using a select and the for xml clause
The resulting xml files are opened in excel, and I need to add custom headers for each column / field
Can I specify custom headers name in the sql script?

As requested by Shnugo, here is a sample of the xml used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<VendorServices>
  <VendorService>
    <VendorServiceId>0</VendorServiceId>
    <VendorId>0</VendorId>
    <ServiceId>0</ServiceId>
    <Cover>0</Cover>
    <Percentage>0</Percentage>
    <TechRateHr>0</TechRateHr>
    <HelperRateHr>0</HelperRateHr>
  </VendorService>
  <VendorService>
    <VendorServiceId>1</VendorServiceId>
    <VendorId>1</VendorId>
    <ServiceId>1</ServiceId>
    <Cover>0</Cover>
    <Percentage>0</Percentage>
    <TechRateHr>0</TechRateHr>
    <HelperRateHr>0</HelperRateHr>
  </VendorService>
</VendorServices>
```

I can open it with Excel 2013, Excel ask me if I want to open like xml table and some other options, and then ask about the creation of a schema

Comment: How are you opening these files in Excel? Please give more information...

Comment: the xml files are associated with excel, so I'm opening from windows explorer directly

Comment: Please use the edit option to add a (reduced) example of your xml. I don't think that Excel can open any xml natively ...

Comment: @Shnugo question updated with information about the xml used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked with your example. This is not really an answer, but to much for a comment... Maybe it's enough for you to find a full solution.

Well, Excel has (limited) support to add XML natively and treat it as data source. If there is a schema (XSD) included, it will be used, if not, Excel will create a schema from your data automatically.

I used [this online tool](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html) to create a schema from your example data:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="VendorServices">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="VendorService" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="VendorServiceId"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="VendorId"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="ServiceId"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="Cover"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="Percentage"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="TechRateHr"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="HelperRateHr"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

As you can see, your column heads are created from the elements names... I did not find to add a differing information for an element's caption. But maybe there is a way to do this...

If this schema was included in your file or saved as XML-source within Excel you'd at least make the opening process a bit easier.

You might do one of the following:

- Export your data with the element names wanted using `FOR XML PATH` directly from T-SQL (Maybe show your actual query if you need help)
- Use `XSLT` to transform your existing XML
- Use VBA or any other programming language for indiv handling
- Try to create the XML format, Excel is using itself. `XLSX`files are nothing else than a ZIP-file which you can rename to `FileName.zip` and open. You'd need the `/xl/worksheets/*.xml` files only. Maybe `sharedStrings.xml`. But I think you can learn the basic format easily.

You might read this [tutorial for Excel and XSD](http://digitalcommons.wayne.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1103&context=libsp)

Comment: Thanks for the info, now I'm trying to generate the xml and inline schema with c# code, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39047253/xml-file-opened-in-excel-must-have-custom-column-headers

Comment: Hi, when you found a solution, please poste it here and accept your own answer. Anybody else might search for the same and find it helpful. If you find my answer helpful, it would be nice to vote it up, thx!