# XML file opened in excel must have custom column headers

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm generating a xml file in .Net using xmldocument
I need to open that file in excel and every column must have a custom header in the first row
How can I embed the column names in the generated xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the Open XML SDK.

See this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh180830(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do some testing